# Cumulative Values row wise and with date filter minimum and maximum in DAX(Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help in calculating the cumulative frequencies row wise with minimum date and maximum date selection by users using sliders. Here is the table that I want to generate could you please guide me? I've tried various function and methods but nothing is giving me right answer. Thanks a lot in advance.
Below is the table that I've and I want to generate:

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwixe.png)

[Desired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oZqK.png)

Answer (score 0):

To create a running total, create a new measure in your table like this (where `Table` is the name of your table):

```
Running Total = CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Values]);
        FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Table'); 'Table'[Date] <= SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date]))
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Have developed almost similar solution based on ID and it also gave me result.

Comment: Can you help me with M-Query for the same?. Because I want to un-pivot it. Thanks

Comment: Update your question to explain what exactly you want to do and add expected output.